# Error loading .xib - application crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface-builder, exc-bad-access

I am banging my head against a brick wall. I am trying to push a view onto a UINavigationController in the usual manner:

```
[[self navigationController]pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

When I do this the app crashes with the following error:

```
 __CFStringEncodeByteStream + 17
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2,address=xxxxx)
```

Now, I have replaced the ViewController in question with a template provided by XCode and I do not get the error so the issue must be with my UIViewController class. Furthermore, if I replace the nib name with that of the template UIViewController class it works .i.e.

```
MyViewController *myVc = [[MyViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"XCodeViewController" bundle:nil];
```

This leads me to think that the issue is actually with the nib and not the class itself. I have checked through all the connections and there are no errors or warnings.

Hopefully somebody can help.

Thanks

Comment: You should post more codes in your `MyViewController`

Comment: There are lots of calls to external classes within MyViewController but if I follow the process above where I call a different nib name in the constructor then the logic is executed perfectly. This is what makes me think that the issue is with the .xib file

Comment: change your initialization code to  `MyViewController *myVc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"XCodeViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];`

Comment: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` means it can't access what you are telling it to access this is because it is looking in `nil` bundle when looking for the nib of name "XCodeViewController", so the bundle needs to change to `[NSBundle mainBundle]` this is the only thing I can tell is wrong with your code.

Comment: While technically correct Popeye, that is not going to change anything in this case. If the bundle parameter is set to nil it automatcially looks in the main bundle anyway.

Comment: Then you need to provide more information then as your error could then be in the nib/view controller file that is being loaded. If there is an error in the code of your new nib file it will appear around this line making it seem like the error is in a wrong ViewController. But I have had this before when setting bundle to nil so that was my first guess.

Comment: The error is definitely not in the ViewController class instance because of the test I have done above - pointing the instance to a different nib does not create the crash and the logic within is completed correctly.I have just done a diff on this nib files in XCode to a version I committed yesterday that worked and there are lots of differences. I am going to step through them and see what I can come up with. I am working on a branched version of a working project so I can not understand where the issues are coming from. Unless something funky is happening when branching in Xcode....

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with a very frustrating bug similar to yours, and everything was in place.
The newly created xib was added to the Bundle resources, no nil pointers or released pointer, NSZombieEnabled was set. The File's Owner was set to the correct ViewController as well

After sitting down with my senior for 30 minutes, we finally realized what was wrong -

In the newly created Xib, even after you assign the File's Owner to the ViewController there is an additional step which you need to take.
You need to have the main View's referencing Outlet set to the File's owner as well. The easiest way to do this is to Drag the "+" sign on the referencing outlet(From the Connections inspector) to the "File's Owner" in the Document Outline. After this you just need to click on "view" which pops up and you should be good.

Hope that helps you or anyone else facing the same problem

Comment: Saved me from pulling my hair out longer than I did. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your nib is added to the application bundle. You can do that by selection you project file->Build Phases->Copy Bundle Resources.
If it is not there, add it.

I had the same issue yesterday and this was the problem.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response but that is not the issue. All of the xibs are included in the Bundle Resources

Answer (score 0):

Need more info to answer, I can give few possibilities.

Check if the class name is mapped properly in your identity inspector.
And check your connections too. If your view is mapped in xib., etc.
If your running the app in OS below 6.0 & built with features such as Auto layout, it leads to crash.

There are multiple possibilities.

Hope this gives an insight.

Comment: yes, iOS < 6 will crash when Auto Layout is enabled, but the error message is not `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Comment: Thanks Jay but I have already checked those. All connections in IB are correct and I have actually disabled auto layout for the view. The class is mapped correctly as well. This is frustrating but thanks for your help

Comment: It is the EXC_BAD_ACCESS element that is worrying as there are no missed connections and there is certainly no memory mismanagement (I am using ARC). Much confused